# Best way to enumerate nomenclature ID's for use by JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, enumeration

In case you have a nomenclature DB table and your application and DAL logic is based on different values within you should be able to identify those values. I do it with enums but I guess there might be a better approach. My way (very stripped code):

Let's say we have entities Pet and Genus (mapping to DB tables).

```
class Pet{int genusId; int id;}

class Genus{
   int id;
   public enum VALUES{
      CAT(0), DOG(1), PARROT(2);
      public final int id;
      private VALUES(int id){this.id = id;}
   }
}
```

And querying goes like:

```
TypedQuery<Pet> q = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p where p.genusId in (:genusIds)");
q.setParameter("genusIds", Arrays.asList(Genus.VALUES.DOG.id, Genus.VALUES.CAT.id));
```

I couldn't get relevant google hits so I guess I might be on the wrong track.

The most popular alternative for keeping nomenclature ID's for the use of application logic is by constants, e.g.:

```
interface MyConst{
   public static final int GENUS_CAT_ID = 0;
   ...
}
```

How would you store your ID's?

Comment: looks fine for me. One thing that reminds your approach is the single table inheritance in JPA. see http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm#CEGDJIFH maybe it's what you're looking for

Comment: I can't see single table inheritance having to do anything with nomenclature id enumeration. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: sorry, then I think I don't understand what you want to know exactly. Are you asking if it's ok to use numbers to identify types in your DB?

Comment: I've reworked the question a bit. Hope it's more clear now.